# how to use model created in rapidminer using java

Tags: java, eclipse, rapidminer

I'm a student trying to use a model created by Rapidminer in a java created application

Do You have any idea how to start the project

Answer (score 0):

In the official Rapidminer website you have a very well explained tutorial on how to create a rapidminer project in eclipse.

I copy the exact link where it explains the process in detail from the beginning.

https://docs.rapidminer.com/latest/developers/creating-your-own-extension/setting-up/using-eclipse.html

I hope this helps you.